# Language switcher Block is not working in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am using language switcher block to make my drupal website linguistic. It showing language switcher block but when i click to any language then content is not translated. URL is changed based on language select.

I am using [language switcher](http://drupal.org/project/language_switcher) & [Internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module.

I already added languages by going through config/languages. I also publish my content by enabling Multilingual support with translation. In translate tab i enables the operation as translated.

Actually I follow all the steps but don't know why my content is not translated. I can't figure out problems. Any one can give me some pointers??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working now....

go through this site http://localize.drupal.org/ and click on your language. Then download your language file (eg drupal-7.21.language-code.po).

Go to admin/config/regional/translate and click on the Import tab. Import the translation package you've just downloaded into the desired language. Go back to the Overview tab. Note the higher percentage for translated strings for the language you added. After that your translational works fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many stages involved when managing Multilingual content, between the various modules involved as well as the Configuration settings, it will probably be quite difficult to debug your problem from afar.

Whenever I set up a multilingual website, I use the same reference
[HowTo: Basic Internationalization setup](http://drupal.org/node/1268692) on [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/).

Since I find it almost impossible to remember every detail of the setup, I avoid any problems by following this guide step by step.

Answer (score -1):

Please go to *Configuration - Regional and language - Languages - Detection and selection*, then enable selection by URL or Sesssion